# HTML5 video not playing in a bxSlider slideshow on iOS (possibly caused by fitvids.js)

Tags: html5-video, bxslider, fitvids

When I place video into a slide on bxSlider, it plays as it should on desktop browsers, but when tested on iOS devices - iPhone and iPad, video will not play.

I've included the current html code. I have duplicated the `<video>` element underneath the slideshow which plays as it should on all devices.

As per the [bxSlider guide on video](http://bxslider.com/examples/video), I have included the *jquery.fitvids.js* file. The issue may be to do with that plugin, as when I remove that, the video in the slide plays, however, the slideshow then does not function correctly (duplicated slide is visible and controls are missing).

Another unexpected thing to note is that when the script initialising bxSlider is placed in the head beneath the libraries, bxSlider doesn't initiate at all.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLu2N/2/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vid test</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <video width="100%" height="300" id="video1" controls preload="auto">
            <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Becel_15s.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Becel_15s_120822b.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Becel_15s_120822b.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
    </li>
</ul>

<video width="100%" height="300" id="video1" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Becel_15s.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Becel_15s_120822b.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Becel_15s_120822b.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>

<script>
    $(".bxslider").bxSlider({
        video: true,
        useCSS: false
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Having this same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your second video tag in 'li' tag and take it inside of that 'ul' tag.

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <video width="100%" height="300" id="video1" controls preload="auto">
            <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Becel_15s.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Becel_15s_120822b.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Becel_15s_120822b.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
    </li>
<li>
<video width="100%" height="300" id="video1" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Becel_15s.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Becel_15s_120822b.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://dev.kirnauskis.com/kirnauskis/design-update01/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Becel_15s_120822b.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
</li>
</ul>
```